# How do I change the authentication model?

Tags: laravel

I need to do authentication to an existing database.
There is a ready table from another service 'Accounts'
It has fields 'Nick' and 'Password'.
I need to authenticate a user using these data and create a session.
I changed 'model' => App\Models\Accounts::class in auth.php,
No errors during authorization,
I log in like this:
Search for user, check password (md5) then if everything is ok - Login via Auth::login($user), But session is not created

Changed the authentication model in auth.php
Created a model of the existing scheme

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Accounts::class,
        ],
```

```
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you implemented for _I log in like this: Search for user, check password (md5) then if everything is ok - Login via Auth::login($user)_

Comment: Please note that the password is not hashed using md5, it is rather hashed using [other hashing algorithms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and verified using [password_verify](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/99fa2e33da0e6534bdc698bc6e6e685303111d5f/src/Illuminate/Hashing/AbstractHasher.php#L26)